# Laravel 5 abort not returning error message

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to throw an error from my Laravel 5.1 app to my frontend Angular app. The thrown errors are not returning the actual status message, which I need:

```
if (Hash::check($updated_profile['current_password'], $user->password)) {
    $user->password = Hash::make($updated_profile['new_password']);
    return $user;
} else {
    abort(500, 'Passwords do not match');
}
```

I've also tried `throw new \Exception('Passwords do not match');`

For both, I get an error on the frontend, but it's missing the status message:

```
Object
  data: null
  headers:(name)
  status: 0
  statusText:""
  __proto__: Object
```

Comment: Are you using an API package or something that warp your controllers ?

Comment: I am wrapping with oauth2 package

Answer (score 0):

It is define in `App class` so if you wanna use it to abort your current request

first define this at top of your controller

```
use App;
```

Then you can use this function like this

```
App::abort(404,'The url not found');
```

Comment: tell where you are using it

Comment: That's not going to work either. I haven't seen the 'message' part work "out-of-the-box" in either Laravel 5, 6, 7, or 8.

Answer (score 0):

Use the response() helper method instead of abort(). Syntax as below:

```
return response("Passwords do not match", 500);
```